# Wordpress Docker Compose Disk Space is Blowing Up

Tags: linux, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

I have an Wordpress Project running with docker-compose. I am hosting the project on Digitalocean and have an issue with the space. The client recognised he couldn't upload new images after days/weeks. I executed `docker system prune --all` and was able to clear some space and upload new media. But after a little time the disk space is full again. `/var/lib/docker/overlay2` is like 25GB. What is this & how can i fix this issue?

Update 1: `docker system prune --all`  now gives me `Total reclaimed space: 0B`

Update 2: I was able to upload some media and change page content again after executing the following commands. The Problem is still that this fix only lasts for some hours and after hours nothing is changeable anymore.

```
docker kill $(docker ps -q)
docker system prune
sudo service apache2 stop
docker-compose up -d
```

Update 3: I investigated a little bit and found a 17GB logfile inside `/var/lib/docker/containers/ID/HASH-json.log`

How can i limit this file size?

Space on server:

[image: Screenshot]

This is how my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

````
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xx
      MYSQL_USER: xx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xx

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./my_theme:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/my_theme
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xx
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xx
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xx

  phpmyadmin:
    image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: xx
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xx
      MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR: db
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}```
````

Comment: Hey @Jonas Schmitt are you able to resolve your issue? If yes, can you tell me what change worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by setting a max size limit for logging files.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "10m"
          max-file: "5"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xx
      MYSQL_DATABASE: xx
      MYSQL_USER: xx
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: xx

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:latest
    volumes:
      - wordpress_data:/var/www/html
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - ./xxx:/var/www/html/wp-content/themes/xx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
    logging:
        driver: "json-file"
        options:
          max-size: "10m"
          max-file: "5"
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: xx
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: xx
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: xx

  phpmyadmin:
    image: corbinu/docker-phpmyadmin
    links:
      - db:mysql
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    environment:
      MYSQL_USERNAME: xxx
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: xxx
      MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR: db
volumes:
  db_data: {}
  wordpress_data: {}
```

Comment: Hey, can provide more details how to set the max size limit for logging files

Comment: @HandsomeCoder i provided the updated docker-compose :)

Answer (score 0):

The `/dev/vda1`, which hosts docker containers too, is full, so your overlays cannot grow up.

I suggest you to:

1. Mount an external disk/partition as data storage.
2. Create volumes, data and db too, as a binding to the above storage.

Comment: Thanks for your response but this can not be the right answer. the whole wordpress including plugins, media uploads, database, etc. is only 140mb and the droplet size is 25gb. this should be more than enough